# JTable becomes blank after executing update on table?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I am trying to write some software where when a user adds a new entry to a SQL database, my JTable showing the entries in the database updates. Currently, when the method `updateTable(Object[][] data)` is called, it results in the table becoming blank.

Would anyone know of a fix for this type of issue?

Here is the code for the method:

```
    /**
     * This method updates the JTable which shows the Amp Settings.
     *
     * @param data A 2D Array of Objects witch represents the data in the
     * database.
     */
    private void updateTable(Object[][] data)
    {
        // A new DefaultTableModel.
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();

        // Looping over the data, create a new row and add it to the DataModel.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            Object[] row = new Object[data[i].length];

            // Fill the row's data.
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = data[i][j];
            }

            // Set the row in the table model.
            dtm.addRow(row);
        }

        // Set the model of the table to the newly created DefaultTableModel.
        table.setModel(dtm);
        
        ((AbstractTableModel) table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
    }
```

Here is the code which calls `updateTable()`:

```
// Calls update table, SERVER.dbtoArray() returns a 2D Array of objects.
updateTable(SERVER.dbToArray());
```

Comment: It is very hard if not impossible for strangers such as us to guess what is wrong with your code based on a small uncompilable snippet, and in cases where you're asking about why it's misbehaving (suggesting that you don't know the cause), you could very well be posting code that has nothing to do with the error. Much better would be if you created a new small compilable and runnable program, explicitly for this question, code small enough to fit in the question yet complete enough to compile, run and show the error for us, a [mre]. The link will explain what this and how it can help.

Comment: To reiterate: I'm not asking for your entire program, nor a link to a code base, but rather a new small program as per the instructions in the [mre] link.

Comment: Unrelated issue: you should *never* be making a call such as this `((AbstractTableModel) table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();` outside of the model itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Even though you add data to the TableModel you didn't add any column names so as far as the table is concerned there are 0 columns to display.

Your code should be something like:

```
String[] columnNames = { "Column1", "Column2", "..." );
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
```

Or a better approach would be to use:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
dtm.setRowCount(0);
```

This will keep the existing columns and just add the data.

Also you don't need to recreate the row array. You already have the data as a row in your 2D array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    Object[] row = data[i];
    model.addRow( row );
}
```